# Magento2: Issue with the customer custom attribute and custom tab in product view

Tags: event-observer, customer-attribute

This is the code snippet responsible for adding new attribute

```
 public function createAllowRequestSampleCustomerAttribute($setup)
        {
            $code = 'allow_request_sample';
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'allow_request_sample',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Allow request sample',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'source' => Boolean::class,
                    'required' => false,
                    'visible' => false,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'position' => 999,
                    'system' => 0,
                    'default' => 1,
                    'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit'],
                ]
            );
    
            $attribute = $this->customerAttribute->loadByCode(Customer::ENTITY, $code);
    
            $attribute->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => 1,
                'attribute_group_id' => 1,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ])->save();
        }
```

Observer that is supposed to hide the custom tab in product view when the attribute is disabled or  it's a guest account (not logged-in).

```
<?php

namespace Alex\RequestSample\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class LayoutGenerateBlocksAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Registry $registry,
        Session  $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return LayoutGenerateBlocksAfter
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!$product) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($this->requestFormDisallowed()) {
            $layout = $observer->getLayout();
            $sampleRequestBlock = $layout->getBlock('request.sample.tab');
            if ($sampleRequestBlock) {
                $sampleRequestBlock->setTemplate('');
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    private function requestFormDisallowed()
    {
        return !$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getAllowRequestSample();
    }
}
```

For some reason, it's always hidden regardless of the settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $this->requestFormDisallowed() this condition is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be fine. However, there may be a problem with the customer attribute value, possibly resulting in a consistent false value being returned.

It is advisable to verify/output the value of `$this->requestFormDisallowed()` in all cases (if-else cases).

**Updated Solution:**

Please load the customer by customer id (customer id can be fetched from the customer session). After loading the customer, get the `allow_request_sample` attribute value from the customer object.

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
protected $customerSession;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \ Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
) {
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
```

**Now load the customer:**

```
$customerSession = $this->customerSession->create();
$customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); // fetch the customer id from the customer session
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

$customer->getAllowRequestSample();
```

OR

```
$customer->getData('allow_request_sample');
```

OR

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('allow_request_sample')->getValue();
```

In this way, You will get the correct value instead of the null value.

Comment: it always returns true leading to removing the block.

also, it can see the customerId that is logged in, in my case it's a completely new one with id 5, but in the debug session it returns a null. maybe that's the issue?

Comment: You have used ! to the below line:
!$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getAllowRequestSample()
is there specific reason using this? Also are you getting the getAllowRequestSample() value that is saved into the database?

Comment: unfortunately, it returns null, thus the whole expression !$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getAllowRequestSample() is true

Comment: apparently, getAttribute('allow_request_sample') allows me to retrieve all the information about the attribute, but I don't know how to get the value from there...
getDefaultValue() works, but it's always 1 and shows the block all the time.

Comment: It is returning 1 always because the attribute default value is 1. You have to load the customer by customer id (customer id can fetched from the customer session) and then get the allow_request_sample attribute value from the loaded customer object.

Comment: I have updated the answer & added the solution. Please try it once, this should work.

Comment: why do you hardcode customerId? doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151081/discussion-between-dramorian-and-magedivine).